# Making ServiceProvider Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I recently watched a video from jeffery way on the pusher real time system. I have everything working correctly. My question refers to a comment he made during the video. He had this code inside his route.php:

```
        App::bind('Pusher', function($app){
        $options = array(
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            'encrypted' => true
        );
        $keys = $app['config']->get('services.pusher');
        return new Pusher($keys['public'], $keys['secret'], $keys['app_id'], $options);
    });
```

He comments that this could should be moved from the routes.php to a service provider but doesn't go any further into detail. Ive been looking up service providers but not quite understanding yet. How do i move this a to service provider correctly?

https://github.com/laracasts/Pusher-Lesson/blob/master/app/routes.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good practice to register all services in Laravel's service providers. Service providers are located in **app/Providers** folder - The definition of **Pusher** service should indeed be moved to either **AppServiceProvider** that is already in there there - just add the service definition in its **register** method:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function register()
  {
    $this->registerPusher();
  }

  private registerPusher() {
    $this->app->bind('Pusher', function($app){
      $options = array(
        'cluster' => 'eu',
        'encrypted' => true
    );
    $keys = $app['config']->get('services.pusher');
    return new Pusher($keys['public'], $keys['secret'], $keys['app_id'], $options);
    });
  }
}
```

or you could create a new one (e.g. PusherServiceProvider) if you want to group related services together:

```
class PushServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function register()
  {
    $this->registerPusher();
  }

  private registerPusher() {
    $this->app->bind('Pusher', function($app){
      $options = array(
        'cluster' => 'eu',
        'encrypted' => true
    );
    $keys = $app['config']->get('services.pusher');
    return new Pusher($keys['public'], $keys['secret'], $keys['app_id'], $options);
    });
  }
}
```

If you decide for the second option, you'll need to register the new provider in your **config/app.php** file - just add it's name to the **providers** array:

```
<?php

  return [
    'providers' => [
      // existing providers
      'App\Providers\PushServiceProvider'
    ],  
  ];
```